# CoffeeScript - function runnning but it "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

appreciate if you help. I have simple function to show (or hide) elements one by one, and it is written in CoffeeScript. The function works great, but my Chrome throws this message in console

> "Uncaught TypeError: elemRoll(...) is not a function"

- what am I doing wrong?

```js
 elemRoll = (elemName, delayDuration, animationDuration) -> 
      amount = $(elemName).length
      $(elemName).each (amount) ->
       $(this).delay(delayDuration * amount).animate { 'opacity': 1 }, animationDuration

$(document).ready -> 
     do elemRoll '.epoch-container .epoch-item', 190, 160
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `do` to simply call a function and rarely would you want to use `do` for that purpose. Your ready-handler should simply be:

```
$(document).ready -> 
  elemRoll '.epoch-container .epoch-item', 190, 160
  # No `do` in here
```

---

[CoffeeScript's `do`](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) is meant to immediately execute an anonymous function:

> CoffeeScript provides the `do` keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments.

Generally it is used as a loop body when you need closure wrappers:

```
for e in array
  do (e) -> ...
```

You can also use it to execute an anonymous function outside a loop:

```
do (a) -> ...
```

becomes this JavaScript:

```
(function(a) { /* ... */ })(a);
```

You can also use it to execute an argument-less function without the parentheses so `do f` becomes `f()`.

Your problem is that this:

```
do a b
```

is interpreted as

```
do a(b)
```

which becomes this JavaScript:

```
a(b)();
```

so your:

```
do elemRoll '.epoch-container .epoch-item', 190, 160
```

is the same as writing:

```
f = elemRoll '.epoch-container .epoch-item', 190, 160
do f
```

and CoffeeScript is assuming that `elemRoll '.epoch-container .epoch-item', 190, 160` will *return* a function.

Also, you need to be very careful and consistent with your whitespace or very confusing things can happen.